# Linux VM with 2GB memory using almost 4GB memory on the macOS Big Sur host

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I have a Kali VM which is running on VMWare Fusion Pro 12.0.0. The VM has been assigned with 2GB memory but on Activity Monitor, I see VMWare process is using 3.80GB of memory. I am pretty sure there is no other VM running. My host is running macOS Big Sur.

Comment: To test if this is application memory for VMWare Fusion versus the guest OS, lower or increase the VM memory, restart and see what usage is like. If it is consistently 3GB (VMWare Fusion) plus memory of the guest OS then you know that 3GB is the amount of RAM VMWare Fusion just needs to exist. Heck, just shut down all guest OS’s and see what RAM usage is like.

Answer (score 1):

The VMware Process is the total amount of VMware memory plus the machine memory.

What you see looks fine to me.

I have a Kali machine in VMware Workstation plus a couple of other machines. Each machine is assigned 3 GB (so 9 GB total).

But the total amount of VMware memory is more in Task Manager because of VMware usage. About 10 GB total (varies a bit up and down).

**Follow up:**  Updates in Virtual Machines consume memory that may or may not be released. So yesterday, 10 GB used, machines all updated, and then today (fresh start up, same machines running), 8 to 9 GB used.  So as I noted earlier, it will vary up and down.